# Jquery - Reset countdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, countdown

I got this plugin from this site http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-countdown-plugin and I manage to run the countdown but I am having problem to stop the countdown when I click a button and reset it. Saw some article about it but can't really relate it to my case. If I call the function again, it will display 4(old counter) --> 9 (new counter) -->3 (old counter) --> 8 (new counter)... together which is messed up. All I need is to stop to reset the counter when I click a button.

countDown code

```
function countDown(){
  $('#countdown').countDown({
    startNumber:10,
    callBack: function(me) {
      $(me).text('Next!').css('color','#090');        
      if(quesNo < lenLevel ){
        //database transaction
      }else {
        alert('finish! You got correct: '+ correct);
      }
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: A tip: _always_ convert tabs to spaces when copy/pasting code _anywhere_ on the web. Configure your editor to use tabs as spaces, every decent editor has this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button handler you will need to "stop" the original count down before starting the new one. The following one line addition to the countDown function should solve your problem.

```
function countDown(){
  $('#countdown').stop();
  $('#countdown').countDown({ ...
```

Comment: thanks for the stop function, I'm wondering if you have any idea how to resume the countDown after stop (As Pause)? Thanks. =]

Comment: there isn't a simple way that I know of to add pause/resume functionality using this plugin. To do that would require a more involved modification of the code.

Answer (score 1):

can u use this instead of plugin 
`var counter = setInterval(startcounter, 10000);`//here calls the function every 10sec u can change

/* later on click do this  */

```
clearInterval(counter );
```